# Input impedance of a line with complex load

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, electrical-resistance, waveguide

I am currently studying electromagnetism mostly with the help of the book "Microwave Engineering" and when trying to solve problems which main goal is to compute the input impedance of a lossless transmission line with a  complex impedance, for example this one:[image]

The formula used to solve this kind of problems is the following one:
$$Z_{in}=Z_0\frac{Z_L+jZ_0\tan\beta l}{Z_0 + jZ_L\tan\beta l}$$
But is is stated that to use this formula, $Z_L$ has to be strictly real, and the approximation to solve this when $Z_L$ is of the form $a+jb$ or just $jb$ it uses the Smith Chart, which I am not allowed to use since I can't bring material to the exam.

All the information I have found on the internet uses the Smith Chart and I wonder if there is a way to solve this kind of problems without using it. I'm not asking for the problem of the photo to be solved for me, just some theory to help.